# Is there Fast Travel in ESO?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

My question Is there fast travel in ESO?

I tried the wayshrines and right clicking on them. It only zooms out the map. There are no options presented.

How can I fast travel to even a town wayshrine which I have already visited like Mistral?

Say I need to get to Mistral and I am stuck with a bunch of mob NPCs beating on me in Hazak's hollow and I am too old/young to fight them. Can I fast travel to Mistral?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is fast travel between waypoints and a 'recall' function when out in the field.

Going to a visited wayshrine (one that has blue flame coming out of it) and interacting with it will allow you to warp from that one to ANY wayshrine you've previously unlocked in ANY zone.  This is completely free.

If you're out in the field, however, and just want to quickly recall back to a wayshrine because you're in too deep, you can open your map through the menu and go to a location in any zone that you've previously visited a wayshrine.  Again, clicking on that wayshrine will warp you there, but this costs some money.  From what I've seen, it costs based upon distance and character level.  It's still fairly cheap, though, and you can easily make the money back from selling things.

An alternate thing I've found is that if you're in a group, you can fast-travel to your group leader.  This helps when you just got into the group and the leader is all the way in the dungeon already.  Right-click their name in the upper left corner and use the Travel to Player option.  (I think this is it, I will have to verify when I get home)

Comment: You should also add that first teleport in 10 minutes is cheaper. After you go to a wayshrine you get a debuff for 10 minutes (soul summons I think is called) that raises the teleport cost about 5 times.

Answer (score 4):

Left-clicking a wayshrine you've already visited on the map (it will be white) will take you there.

Normally it will cost you a few coins, but if you approach and interact with another wayshrine to open your map, it will be free.

Answer (score 1):

You can fast travel to any wayshrine you have already visited via your map at the cost of gold (which increases if you have previously used this feature recently).

You can fast travel to any wayshrine you have already visited from any other wayshrine for free.

You can also port to any player in your group OR in any of your guilds (as long as they are of the proper alliance and in a zone you can visit. This is why I never pay for wayshrines. Just port to someone in your guild and then port from that wayshrine to wherever you want to go for free.

Answer (score -1):

Once the wayshrine is activated, it can be used by left click. When left-clicked, it opens up the local/world map. Then, choose the desired wayshrine where you want to travel using left-click. That's it.